# Example 3, Sobolev space Evans

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In the following example p.260 Evans. [image]

I think I understand everything except for one calculus fact in the second last equation:
$$ \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)}\varepsilon^{-\alpha}\,dS=\varepsilon^{n-1-\alpha}.
$$

Could anyone show me how the integral computed explicitly?

Comment: That integral is just $\varepsilon^{-\alpha}$ times the volume of $\partial B(0,\varepsilon)$; this latter thing has a sort of ugly formula, but it's a constant times $\varepsilon^{n-1}$. Googling around for volume of sphere should find a proof.

Comment: @math101 I get lost after "Now if $\alpha +1 < n$, $|Du(x)| \in L^1$". Why is that true? And where does the middle inequality come from?

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that they are equal, instead the left hand side is bounded by the right hand side multiplied by some constant that is independant of $\epsilon$, it seems to be part of the the $C$ in the example. This fact arises because $\partial B(0,\epsilon)$ is an $n-1$ dimensional object, so $$\int_{\partial B(0,\epsilon)}\,dS=|\partial B(0,\epsilon)|\le C\epsilon^{n-1}.$$ Now multiply by $\epsilon^{-\alpha}$ and you get result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible explicit calculation:

Let $A$ be the area of the unit sphere $S(0,1)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n;\ |x|=1\}$. Employing polar coordinates (see Theorem 2.49 in the [Folland's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=wI4fAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Gerald%20B.%20Folland%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CDIQ6AEwA2oVChMI-d-tzO29xwIVDIOQCh1gcQiZ#v=onepage&q&f=false)) we conclude that

$$\int_{B(0,\varepsilon)}1\ dx=\int_0^\varepsilon\int_{\partial B(0,1)} r^{n-1}\ dS\ dr=A\int_0^\varepsilon r^{n-1}\ dr=A\frac{\varepsilon^n}{n}.$$

Thus, by item (ii) of Theorem 4 in appendix C.3 of the [Evans book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Lawrence%20C.%20Evans%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAmoVChMIl_-36e29xwIVyUOQCh3Obgny#v=onepage&q&f=false),

$$\int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)}\varepsilon^{-\alpha}\;dS=\varepsilon^{-\alpha}\int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)}1\ dS=\varepsilon^{-\alpha}\left(\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\int_{B(0,\varepsilon)}1\ dx\right)=A\varepsilon^{n-1-\alpha}.$$