# Example 3 - Section 5.5.2 - Partial Differential Equations by Evans

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Firstly, I would like to say that I know that there are many topics asking about this example ([topic 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386128/take-u-b00-1-to-be-the-unit-ball-in-mathbb-rn-and-consider-ux-x?rq=1), [topic 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1982320/proving-x-alpha-in-w1-pu?rq=1) and [topic 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1274280/example-3-sobolev-space-evans)), but I didn't find a topic with the same doubt that I have.

The following example:

[image]

I didn't understand how the author stated that $|\int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} u \phi \nu^i dS| \leq ||\phi||_{L^{\infty}} \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} \varepsilon^{- \alpha} dS$

I think what happens here is the following:

$|\int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} u \phi \nu^i dS| \leq \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} |u \phi \nu^i| dS = \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} |\varepsilon^{-\alpha} \phi \nu^i| dS = \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} |\varepsilon^{-\alpha}| \ |\phi| \ |\nu^i| dS \leq \int_{\partial B(0,\varepsilon)} |\varepsilon^{-\alpha}| \ |\phi| dS$,

but I don't know what to do now, I think that I need to use the fact that if $f \in L^1$ and $g \in L^{\infty}$, then $fg \in L^p$ and $||fg||_{L^1} \leq ||f||_{L^1} ||g||_{L^{\infty}}$, but I don't know if I can use this because I don't know if $\phi \in L^{\infty}$. Anyone can help me to understand this inequality? Thanks in advance!

$\textbf{P.S.:} \ C^{\infty}_c(U)$ is the space of all $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$-functions $\phi: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with compact support in $U$.

Comment: I upvoted as soon as I saw the links. It is good to provide links between questions and answers, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi\in C_c^{\infty}$. Continuous functions on compact sets are bounded.

Comment: I don't belive that I let it pass, thanks a lot!